# Hexadecimal Addressing

Tags: api, hex, fpga, memory-address

I'm confused about the bottom statement from this API's documentation. The API is meant to control an FPGA using Python commands. From the first line I can conclude that the 0x07 is the address of the input wire, but how does bit 3 get written with a value of 1 in the bottom command?

Converting 04 from hex to decimal gives: `(0*16^1 + 4*16^0 = 4)` which only adds to my confusion.

Here is the [link](https://library.opalkelly.com/library/FrontPanelAPI/classokCFrontPanel.html#a74f8b4b37ccc57dd72b5b739bbc45766).

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the code is python?

Comment: Neither the return value or th link are python, so i have removed the tag. You can quickly tell it is not python because the variables are declared. In fact the front page states `c++`.  Please confirm and add a new tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common way to handle single bits in a register. You need to think how the numbers are represented *in binary* (don't try to convert it to decimal as it won't help).

Hardware registers use single bits (or group of bits) for enabling/disabling features, so it's really common to wanting to write a particular bit by first selecting the register with its address and then writing the bits you are interested in.

The easiest way to write single bits is to write the number in binary, so say that I need to set only the first and the fourth I would write `0b1001`. In order to keep things more concise usually people write the hex equivalent, which in this example is 0x9.

In your example `0x4 = 0b100` so you are writing to the third bit.

If you don't want to overwrite the entire word you can use a mask as well which changes only the bits selected by the mask or you can do it manually by reading first the value of the register and then using these operations:

```
// Turn on only the n-th bit
reg = reg OR (1<<n)

// Turn off only the n-th bit
reg = reg AND ~(1<<n)
```

If you want to learn more you can look at bitwise operations and any microcontroller manual.

Comment: Okay, so I guess 0x04 is listed twice since the value and the mask are the same? So If I wanted to change the second bit to a 1 then the value and mask would be 0x02? Similarly, would changing the second bit to a zero require 0x00 and 0x00?

Comment: From the docs *In addition, specific bits may be updated independent of other bits within an endpoint by using the optional mask.* so the mask defines which bits are affected. I believe you can write `xem->SetWireInValue(0x07, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0x02);` or `xem->SetWireInValue(0x07, 0x02, 0x02);` as they will do the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter in SetWireInValue is the input address, the second parameter is the `val` which tells the API what values to assign to the bits in the WireIn. The third parameter is the `mask` which tells the API WHICH bits to update. Specifically, the bits which are `1` in the mask are assigned the values in the corresponding bits in the value. Bits which are `0` in the mask are not updated.